# how to turn off hyperlinks in text messages on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I received a text message from my wife and on my end the phrase `the crickets` was underlined, and when I tapped it, it took me to a Wikipedia article on Buddy Holly's band The Crickets.

When I asked her if she had done something special on her end to cause that, she said no, and in my own text to her the words were turned into a hyperlink too.  This is happening automatically.

She was referring to the insects, not to the band.

What is this inane feature called and how is it turned off?

[image: iPhone text message with hyperlink]

Comment: Wild guess but check after settings -> Siri and search -> messages, turn off Siri&suggestions

Comment: Abracadabra, it worked :)  If you make it an answer I will upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings -> Siri and Search -> Messages, turn off Siri & suggestions .

It is not present in Messages-> Siri(absent), otherwise it were intuitive, like Safari -> Siri(Present).